# Declaring the correct type for an Angular Reactive Forms cross property validator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-validate-angular-reactive-forms/) the author implements a password check validator like this:

```
  MatchPassword(password: string, confirmPassword: string) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const passwordControl = formGroup.controls[password];
      const confirmPasswordControl = formGroup.controls[confirmPassword];

      if (!passwordControl || !confirmPasswordControl) {
        return null;
      }

      if (confirmPasswordControl.errors && !confirmPasswordControl.errors.passwordMismatch) {
        return null;
      }

      if (passwordControl.value !== confirmPasswordControl.value) {
        confirmPasswordControl.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
      } else {
        confirmPasswordControl.setErrors(null);
      }
    }
  }
```

No return type is set for the function.  This leads to linting errors in Angular 13.

I've tried to fix the linting errors by changing the signature of the cross property validation function to this:

```
   MatchPassword(password: string, confirmPassword: string):ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null | undefined { ...
```

However now the linter errors on the signature of the validation function that is returned:

```
...
     return (formGroup: FormGroup):ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null | undefined => {
...
```

```
Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn | AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[] | null | undefined'.
  Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    Types of parameters 'formGroup' and 'control' are incompatible.
      Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.ts(2322)
```

This does not happen on Stackblitz, only on new Angular 13 projects, thus I can't create a Stackblitz for it.

Anyone know how to declare the signature for Reactive Form Validators that perform cross property validation?

### LINTING PROGRESSION

For those wondering, the very first linting error occurs within the registration component that is assigning the cross property validator.

It creates the `FormGroup` instance and the custom cross property validator is assigned as the third argument like this:

```
new FormGroup('', ..., this.v. MatchPassword('password', 'confirmPassword'))
```

And that is where the first linting error occurs.

** Side Note **
`this.v` is the injected validation service containing the `MatchPassword` function.

The linting error generated says this:

```
Argument of type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null | undefined'.
  Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    Types of parameters 'formGroup' and 'control' are incompatible.
      Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.ts(2345)
```

Comment: can you provide the first error you got before ?

Comment: @dt170 sure.  I added it under Linting Progression.  The very first linting error occurs in the registration component using the cross property validation function.

Comment: Could you provide the code that's failing, and how it's used? It seems like you've typed both `MatchPassword` **and** the anonymous function it returns as returning `ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null | undefined` (which is very broad - could you not rule out either of them returning an array, at least?)

Comment: Looking at https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group it seems that tutorial is using a deprecated call, options is `{ [key: string]: any; }` which isn't type-safe.

Comment: I don't see a new FormControl in the post, but in the meantime the compiler tells you what type it's inferred and you can see how that matches the implementation. Why not start with that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. This has all the code in it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nurvy5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fregistration.component.ts

Comment: Let's not do that again...

Comment: @jonrsharpe The abbreviated version of the `FormGroup`  is defined like this: `new FormGroup('', ..., this.v. MatchPassword('password', 'confirmPassword'))

Comment: Also, the cross property validator is passed as the third argument to the `FormGroup`....And earlier I said `FormControl` ... so just making a correction ...

Comment: I updated the LINTING PROGRESSION section with a more detailed description of where the first linting error occurs.

Comment: I created a bug report for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44880

Comment: all the problem is that you forget a `return null` and the end of code. To try to explain "how work". The author makes use of one property of the validators: it is executed each time any formControl of the formGroup change. Then use setErrors to give manually the error. Really is a bad idea, because you can has anothers validators in the formControl (e.g. you can add a min or max number of character or a required validator)

Comment: @Eliseo see my answer.  The interface used in the tutorial produces lint errors with Angular 13.

Comment: @Ole, only return null if happens one of the two first condition, not the last if..else

Comment: @Eliseo Angular 13 also produces linting errors if all branches do not return a value, therefore null is returned .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you'd like to do cross field validation that is easy because when passed into the `new FormGroup(...)` the validator gets the actual `FormGroup`. but for typing Angular has `(control: AbstractControl)` and that is fine because
`FormGroup` is actually a type of `AbstractControl`. so all you need to do is to check that this is a `FormGroup` and not one of the other types of `AbstractControl` s so you could do

```
   MatchPassword(password: string, confirmPassword: string) {
     return (control: AbstractControl) => {
         const isFormGroup = control instanceof FormGroup;
         if (!isFormGroup) {
            return null
         }
        // do what ever you'd like...
        const passwordControl = formGroup.controls[password];
        const confirmPasswordControl = formGroup.controls[confirmPassword];
```

Answer (score -1):

OK so, per input from the Angular team, we changed the interface for the validator to the expected interface and also changed the implementation correspondingly.

The key is that we can use `AbstractControl.get` to get all the controls on the form and this allows us to use the `ValidatorFn` interface.

This is the new implementation:

```
   passwordMatch(password: string, confirmPassword: string):ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: AbstractControl):{ [key: string]: any } | null => {
      const passwordControl = formGroup.get(password);
      const confirmPasswordControl = formGroup.get(confirmPassword);
      
      if (!passwordControl || !confirmPasswordControl) {
        return null;
      }

      if (
        confirmPasswordControl.errors &&
        !confirmPasswordControl.errors.passwordMismatch
      ) {
        return null;
      }

      if (passwordControl.value !== confirmPasswordControl.value) {
        confirmPasswordControl.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
        return { passwordMismatch: true }
      } else {
        confirmPasswordControl.setErrors(null);
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: what's strange is that although the type is correct, if you put a `console.log` in the validator you will see that it is actually the `FormGroup` and the `.controls` are available... but if you do `(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null` you will get an error that it is not assignable to `ValidatorFn`